# How to assign node names to a matrix Networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to draw a graph in NetworkX. The network connects 30 nodes and about 130 edges.
Nodes are set using a matrix with weight

```
A = [
    [0, 1.51, 0, 1.71, 0],
    [0, 0, 2.11, 1.81, 2.31],
    [0, 0, 0, 1.31, 1.41],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

How to assign the names of the nodes to the matrix from list `("A1", "K2", ... "Z30")`?
So far, I have only been possible to assign names to numbers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = [[0, 1.51, 0, 1.71, 0],
     [0, 0, 2.11, 1.81, 2.31],
     [0, 0, 0, 1.31, 1.41],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.matrix(A), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")
lab_node = dict((i, str(i)*3) for i in range(5))
nx.draw(G, layout)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout, node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, layout, edge_labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, layout, labels=lab_node, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple workaround, you can turn your adjacency matrix `A` into a pandas DataFrame whose columns/indices are the labels you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

A = [
    [0, 1.51, 0, 1.71, 0],
    [0, 0, 2.11, 1.81, 2.31],
    [0, 0, 0, 1.31, 1.41],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

labels = ['alice', 'bob', 'charlie', 'dan', 'ellie']
```

To create the DataFrame:

```
A2 = pd.DataFrame(A, index=labels, columns=labels)
```

Check the result by drawing it, with no additional setting of labels (showing that we already set it right):

```
nx.draw_networkx(nx.from_pandas_adjacency(A2))
```

[image]

Comment: This does not help OP with the label syntax they want.

Comment: This is the label syntax they provided in the example.

Comment: And, again, they only need to provide a list of labels - any list they want.

Comment: @AKX Anyway, I've edited my answer to clarify according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only the drawing you can use the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = [[0, 1.51, 0, 1.71, 0],
     [0, 0, 2.11, 1.81, 2.31],
     [0, 0, 0, 1.31, 1.41],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.matrix(A), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")
# lab_node = dict((i, "A") for i in range(5))

# a list of the node labels in the right order
raw_labels = ["A1", "K2", "D3", "E4", "Z30"]
lab_node = dict(zip(G.nodes, raw_labels))

nx.draw(G, layout)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout, node_size=500)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, layout, edge_labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, layout, labels=lab_node, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.show()
```

If you want to rename the nodes in your graph, you are probably looking for the [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html) method.